# bhopal jail escape how to solve in python?

Tags: python-3.x

A prison escape a man can jump x distance but slips down y distance.there will be N number of compound wall.how many total jumps to escape?

example input
10
1
1
10

output
1

example 2:
5
1
4
9
10
11
5

output
9

input1 is max distance the person can jump
input2 is slipping distance, input3=list containing height of all compund wall to jump,if input1=5,input2=1,for number of compundwalls=1,
input3=10,the output is obtained as first jump 5 but slip by 1 so only 4
next jump=4+5=9 (<10) but slips to 8 next jump he escapes so output=3

my code

```
import sys import os

def GetJumpCount(input1,input2,input3):
    i=1 
    jmp=0 
    for i in range(0,len(input3)): 
        temp=input3[i] 
        if temp-input1==0: 
            jmp+=1 
        else: 
            while((temp-input1)+input2)>0: 
                temp=(temp-input1)+input2 
                jmp+=1 
            if temp==1: 
                break 
            elif temp<input1: 
                jmp+=1 
            break
    return jmp;

ip1 = int(input()); 
ip2 = int(input()); 
ip3_cnt = 0 
ip3_cnt = int(input()) 
ip3_i=0 
ip3 = [] 
while ip3_i < ip3_cnt: 
ip3_item = int(input()); 
ip3.append(ip3_item) 
ip3_i+=1

output = GetJumpCount(ip1,ip2,ip3) 
print(str(output))
```

Comment: sorry dont know to edit code properly while asking...there is not indendation error ..i need to know if my logic is correct...i got only 30/100 even if i passed the test case

Comment: FYI: Python could very well work with the variable names appearing in the description (x, y, N). Renaming them to input1/2/3 does not help readability

Comment: only the function body was to be completed ..already the parameters were given as input1/2/3...input 1=the max height he can jump,input2=slipping distance, input3 is list containing height of every compound wall @tevemadar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to contain a part of the idea, but it may be worth running through the task on a piece of paper. Also, the goal is to pass one wall. If that is done, passing many of them is really just a loop.

If you jump x and do not slip back (y=0), you can reach the top in `ceil(N/x)` jumps.
It can be followed with the internal loop too, something like

```
jumps=0
x=3
N=5

while N>0:
  jumps=jumps+1
  N=N-x
print(jumps)
```

When slip-back comes into the picture, things are very similar, with a twist: if adding x brings you higher than the wall's top (or below 0 when counting downwards), you will not slip back. So generally you will proceed `x-y` with each jump, but with the last jump you can cross the distance of `x`.

And for the calculation it does not matter if your long jump is the first one or the last one, so you can do it at the start:

```
jumps=0
x=3
y=2
N=5

jumps=jumps+1
N=N-x
while N>0:
  jumps=jumps+1
  N=N-x+y
print(jumps)
```

When the code is done, it is easy to form a one-step calculation too: `ceil((N-x)/(x-y))+1`, for N>=x

By the way, it is something I learned here too: the array can be looped over directly, without checking its length and indexing into it:

```
for N in input3:
  ...
```

And a small disclaimer: I hope these snippets work, but I do not have Python here and now, neither the bandwidth to use some remote access, so I have not tested any of them.

Comment: yes doing by paper is better and i didnt completely understand your explanation..can you explain why my code is wrong even if it is not a right approach i think @tevemadar